# If else in ggplot + switching values between character and numeric for geom_vline

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, geom-vline

I need to integrate `if else` block in ggplot, where depending on value for `variable_to_switch` it will:

- if value is numeric -> plot line
- value is text -> do NOT plot line

*I provide my code in the most complete version to take in account possible conflicts with provided solution.*

```
#  Creating Data ----

obs_number <- 500
mean <- 2
median <- 3
dens_mode <- 2
variable_to_switch <- "Text"
dlt_standard_mean <- 2
cut_off <- 12
max_dlt <- 15

metrics_test <- data.frame(xintercept = c(obs_number,cut_off,max_dlt, 0, mean, median, dens_mode,variable_to_switch, dlt_standard_mean ),
                      label = c("Label 1",
                                "Label 2",
                                "Label 3",
                                "", 
                                "Label 4",
                                "Label 5",
                                "Label 6",
                                "Label 7",
                                "Label 8"))


mean_by_batch_route <- c(rep(1,81), rep(2,252), rep(3,170), rep(4,41))
Label <- c(rep('Label',544))

data_to_plot_test <- data.frame(cbind(Label,mean_by_batch_route))
data_to_plot_test$mean_by_batch_route <- as.numeric(data_to_plot_test$mean_by_batch_route)

# Plotting ---

x_data <- 4

histo_density_plot <- ggplot(data_to_plot_test, aes(x = mean_by_batch_route)) +
  
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 1, colour= "black", fill = "white") +
  geom_density(adjust = 1.75, aes(y=..density..), fill="blue", alpha = .25)

if(variable_to_switch == "Text"){
  
  histo_density_plot <- histo_density_plot +
    
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xintercept, color = label),
               data = metrics_test[c(6,7,9), ], linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5, alpha = 1,
               key_glyph = draw_key_text) +
    
    
    
    scale_color_manual(
      name= "Values",
      limits = metrics_test$label,
      values = c("navyblue","darkcyan", "cyan4", "white", "black", "chartreuse4", "purple","darkgoldenrod3", "red"),
      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = metrics_test$xintercept, 
                                               size = 3)))
  
} else {
  
  histo_density_plot <- histo_density_plot +
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xintercept, color = label),
               data = metrics_test[6:nrow(metrics_test), ], linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5, alpha = 1,
               key_glyph = draw_key_text) +
    
    
    
    scale_color_manual(
      name= "Values",
      limits = metrics_test$label,
      values = c("navyblue","darkcyan", "cyan4", "white", "black", "chartreuse4", "purple","darkgoldenrod3", "red"),
      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = metrics_test$xintercept, 
                                               size = 3)))
  
  
}

histo_density_plot <- histo_density_plot +
  
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 8), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "darkblue", size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face="plain", color="black", 
                                   size=8, angle=0),
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "darkblue", size=8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="plain", color="black", 
                                   size=8, angle=0),
        legend.position = c(.80, .70),
        legend.title=element_text(size=8),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 8)
  )+
  
  
  labs(title = relevant_title, y = "Distribution fors DLT values, frequency", x = "DLT for the route: average DLT per batch, days")+
  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, x_data,
                                  ifelse(x_data <= 20, 1,
                                         ifelse((x_data > 20 & x_data < 50), 5, 10))))

histo_density_plot
```

If `variable_to_switch == "Text"` I will have this error:
`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

For `variable_to_switch` equal to any numeric value plot works.

I want to switch between character and numeric value for `variable_to_switch`.
**Desired output** for case with `variable_to_switch == "Text"` :
[image]

Comment: The column `metrics_test$xintercept` is not numeric, so that's why you're getting the error.  You cannot send a non-numeric value as the `xintercept` for `geom_vline()`.  You can't draw row 6 from that dataset anyway, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand that I cannot send a non-numeric value. But that is the point that sometimes it will be non-numeric. In the meantime I just used 2 different codes for `if` and `else` blocks. It is redundant, but works. I was wondering if there is more elegant solution for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, the main issue is that the `xintercept` column in the dataframe `metrics_test` contains numbers and text.  Data frame columns can only contain one variable type, and the text cannot be a number, so this column will always be a `chr` type, not a `num` type.  You then assign this column to the `xintercept` aesthetic in the `geom_vline()` call, which is where the error message is coming from.

If you are supplying a subset of that dataframe that *does not contain* a text value in `metrics_test$xintercept`, you can get around this issue by forcing the column into a numeric type - just as long as the column no longer contains any text.  In your example code, if you replace the first part of the code with the following, it works without the error:

```
# your code prior to the if/then statement...

if(variable_to_switch == "Text"){
  
  d <- metrics_test[c(6,7,9),]    # temporary data frame
  d$xintercept <- as.numeric(d$xintercept)
  
  histo_density_plot <- histo_density_plot +
    
    geom_vline(aes(xintercept = xintercept, color = label),
               data = d, linetype = "dashed", size = 0.5, alpha = 1,
               key_glyph = draw_key_text) +

    # the rest of the if then statement and code continues as you have it..
```

[image]